# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} nx^{n+1}$ where $x\in(-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} nx^{n+1}$ where $x\in(-1,1)$?

Intuitive I think it's 0. I tried L'Hôpital's but it seems too complicated and I'm sure there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Do you have any guesses? Do you think the limit exists? If people see the effort you have made they will be able to help you better.

Comment: A hint: If you know that the limit exists (do you?) then the limit of the sequence $(n+1)x^{n+2}$ must be the same. If the limit is nonzero, can you obtain contradiction?

Comment: If the limit exists it is *certainly* $0$ because in the case where $x<0$, the limit flips between positive and negative, and the only way for both to be met is if it's $0$, which is technically neither positive nor negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By ratio test

$$\frac{(n+1)x^{n+2}}{nx^{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}x\to x<1$$

Answer (score 3):

If $x=0$, the limit is zero.

If $0 <x <1$ then

$$\ln (nx^{n+1})=\ln (n)+(n+1)\ln (x)=$$
$$(n+1)(\frac {\ln (n)}{n+1}+\ln (x) )$$
which goes to $-\infty $.
the limit is then zero.

If $-1 <x <0$, then
$$x^{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}|x|^{n+1}$$
the limit is also zero.